# jboss-eap-6 HA singleton deploying multiple web archives in standalone configuration

Tags: jboss, singleton, jboss-eap-6

I am able to deploy my ear and wars in my standalone cluster. 2 of my wars are for the HA singleton. Soon after starting the first standalone jboss-eap-6, I start the second. When all my applications have deployed successfully I open J-Console, I notice that one of my singleton war is running on the first jboss-eap-6 and the second singleton war is running on the second jboss-eap-6. Also in Jconsole, there was only 1 jboss-eap-6 reporting as primary.

My question is: Is there some way in jboss-eap-6 standalone.xml I can force only 1 jboss-eap-6 to run the singleton HA wars. Or would I have to package the wars into an ear?

Comment: How are you defining your HA Singletons in the war? Are you using the ServiceActivator decorator to register and start a HA Service?  I am just a little surprised that it works as I assumed those services would not be available from a web container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further evaluation, the 2 singletons eventually would merge together after a few minutes, thus creating 1 intended singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything in `standalone.xml` that would change the behaviour of a war. In any case you should be using `standalone-ha.xml` for a cluster with HA singletons deployed.

The JBoss High Availability Singleton architecture changed significantly between JBoss EAP 5 and 6.

Under JBoss EAP 5 you just placed your deployable object in a `deploy-hasingleton` special deployment folder.  Under JBoss EAP 6 your classes need to implement a JBoss Service Layer, specifically `org.jboss.msc.service.Service` along with a `org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceActivator`. it is the implementation of these service classes that control the instantiation and management of your HA Singleton. I have not tried deploying a hasingleton as a war and I have some doubts because I suspect the dependent service classes may not be available in the web container.

The `ServiceActivator` is responsible for managing the lifecycle of the `Service`. The `ServiceActivator` implementation class needs to be listed in a file `META-INF/service/org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceActivator` for JBoss to activate it during its startup / deployment.

Example:
Create a Service Activator

```
public abstract class SingletonActivator<T extends Serializable> implements ServiceActivator {

    @Override
    public SingletonService<String> instantiateSingleton() {
        return new SingletonService<String>();
    }

    public ServiceName getServiceName() {
         return ServiceName.JBOSS.append("my", "ha", "singleton");
     }


    /**
     * Activated by the Service Activator
     *
     * @param service
     * @param serviceName
     *            - the Singleton Service Name that is registered in the JBOSS cluster
     */
    @Override
    public final void activate(ServiceActivatorContext context) {
        SingletonService<T> service = instantiateSingleton();
        SingletonService<T> singleton = new SingletonService<T>(service, getServiceName());

        /*
         * The NamePreference is a combination of the node name (-Djboss.node.name) and the name of
         * the configured cache "singleton". If there is more than 1 node, it is possible to add more than
         * one name and the election will use the first available node in that list.
         */
        // e.g. singleton.setElectionPolicy(new PreferredSingletonElectionPolicy(new SimpleSingletonElectionPolicy(), new NamePreference("node1/singleton")));
        // or singleton.setElectionPolicy(new PreferredSingletonElectionPolicy(new SimpleSingletonElectionPolicy(), new NamePreference("node1/singleton"), new
        // NamePreference("node2/singleton")));

        singleton.build(new DelegatingServiceContainer(context.getServiceTarget(), context.getServiceRegistry())).setInitialMode(ServiceController.Mode.ACTIVE).install();
    }
}
```

Create A HA Singleton Service Class that is solely responsible for looking up and invoking your EJB containing your business logic

```
public class SingletonService<T> implements Service<T> {
    protected ScheduledExecutorService deployDelayThread = null;

    /**
     * The node we are running on
     */
    protected String nodeName;

    /**
     * A flag whether the service is started (or scheduled to be started)
     */
    protected final AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    /**
     * Container life cycle call upon activation. This will construct the singleton instance in this JVM and start the Timer.
     */
    @Override
    public final void start(StartContext context) throws StartException {
        this.nodeName = System.getProperty("jboss.node.name");
        logger.info("Starting service '" + this.getClass().getName() + "' on node " + nodeName);
        if (!started.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            throw new StartException("The service " + this.getClass().getName() + " is still started!");
        }
        // MSC does not allow this thread to be blocked so we let the service know that the start is asynchronous and the result will be advised later.
        // We delay the actual deployment of the Singleton for a few seconds to allow time for a HASingleton Election to be held and won by one of the instances.
        // If the winner is not this instance (prior to deployemnt) then stop(Context) is invoked which sets started to false and the deployment does not occur.
        // context.asynchronous();
        deployDelayThread.schedule(new StartSingletonAsync(context), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        context.complete();
    }

    /** Introduces a 5s delay in starting the Singleton bean giving time for the the ha singleton election to be held and won */
    private class StartSingletonAsync implements Runnable {

        private StartSingletonAsync(StartContext context) {
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                startSingletonBean();
            } catch (StartException e) {
                logger.info("Start Exception", e);
            }
            // be nice to the garbage collector, we don't need this any more
            deployDelayThread.shutdown();
            deployDelayThread = null;
        }
    }

    private void startSingletonBean() throws StartException {
        try {
            if (!started.get()) {
                throw new StartException("Aborted due to service stopping");
            }
            // Start your EJB
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            bean = ic.lookup(getJndiName());
            bean.startHaSingleton();
            logger.info("*** Master Only: HASingleton service " + getJndiName() + " started on master:" + nodeName);
            if (!bean.isRunning()) {
                logger.error("ERROR Bean should be running");
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throwStartException(e);
        }
    }

    private void throwStartException(Exception e) throws StartException {
        String message = "Could not initialize HASingleton" + getJndiName() + " on " + nodeName;
        logger.error(message, e);
        throw new StartException(message, e);
    }

    /**
     * Container life cycle call when activated
     */
    @Override
    public final void stop(StopContext context) {
        if (deployDelayThread != null) {
            deployDelayThread.shutdownNow();
        }
        if (!started.compareAndSet(true, false) || bean == null) {
            logger.warn("The service '" + this.getClass().getName() + "' is not active!");
        } else {
            try {
                InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
                bean = (JmxMBean) ic.lookup(getJndiName());
                bean.stopHaSingleton();
                logger.info("*** Master Only: HASingleton service " + getJndiName() + " stopped on master:" + nodeName);
            } catch (EJBException e) {
                // Note: all these exceptions are already logged by JBoss 
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                logger.error("Could not stop HASingleton service " + getJndiName() + " on " + nodeName, e);
            }
            logger.info("MASTER ONLY HASingleton service '" + this.getClass().getName() + "' Stopped on node " + nodeName);
        }
    }

    private String getJndiName() {
        return "java.global/path/to/your/singleton/ejb";
    }
}
```

Finally list your Activator class in `META-INF/servcie/org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceActivator`

```
com.mycompany.singletons.SingletonActivator
```

You may also need to add dependencies to the manifest `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file inside your jar as follows: `Dependencies: org.jboss.msc, org.jboss.as.clustering.singleton, org.jboss.as.server`

There is a more extensive implementation guide available from Redhat at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Development_Guide/Implement_an_HA_Singleton.html. You may need to create a Redhat account to access this. There is also a quickstart example in the JBoss distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am using the Service Activator and a class to look up the EJB.  Also, I am using a modified version of the standalone-full-ha.xml. I am modifying my code to be able to package both wars into an ear.